# Best (and shortest) C# book

Tags: c#

I need to prepare for C# interview which book is the best and shortest? Thanks

Comment: Oops! Because it is by mistake...

Comment: Are you looking for a primer to nail down vocabulary while refreshing your existing knowledge? Or are you coming in knowing little if anything about C#?

Comment: Isn't "best" and "shortest" really cutting down the options, possibly to the point of there being none? Assuming that one could objectively measure "best", chances are it's not the "shortest" -- assuming no correlation there is a 1/3500 chance according to a "C# programming" Amazon query. I guess what I'm trying to say is: **Please avoid useless quantifiers and _include more details about what you are really looking for_.**

Answer (score 6):

[Rob Miles C# Yellow Book](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/)

Good, short, and free

Comment: +1 I would rank this the best book for C# starter

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something short, I like the pocket references from O'Reilly: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781449394011/

Normally, you need some knowledge if you want them to be useful though.

Comment: The link is broken now. What was the title?

Comment: The link still works for me. Title is "C# 4.0 Pocket Reference".

Answer (score 3):

Surely you are after [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/) by Mr Skeet..?

Answer (score 1):

[oreilly's Programing c#.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596159838) it is several hundred pages, but it is enough detail to answer interview questions, if you can remember a good portion of what you read.

Answer (score 0):

I would skip through the book found at the following link. [http://www.amazon.com/Pro-2010-NET-Platform-Fifth/dp/1430225491#reader_1430225491](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491). I know that it is 1712 pages, but if you skim through parts of the book that you only have a rough understanding of, you will be better prepared than skimming through a book that is lacking in information.